# Is space habitation a technology problem or is it really just a mass (cost) problem?

Tags: space-station, technology, habitat, sustainability

There are a lot of challenges with space habitation. Gravity, radiation, fuel for reactions to maneuver, water, atmosphere, food, etc. etc.

NASA and many others are working on all kinds of solutions for these, which makes it seem like a technology problem, but isn't this really a mass (or cost) problem? For example, if I could put as much mass in orbit (with cost not being an issue), wouldn't all of these problems be solved? Radiation -> Super thick walls, maybe water barriers as well
Gravity -> Sufficient mass for large diameter rotating station
Fuel or Water -> Plenty can be added/stored
Food -> With enough mass, enough space can be allocated for food production.

The list goes on, but the question is, are there problems we can't solve with just extra mass, or are all of the technical problems we have only technology problems because we're limited on cost and thus mass?

Comment: "wouldn't all of these problems be solved?" yes, but when your on as tight of a budget as space agencies that isnt a solution. it would be extremely  inefficient and not worth it, which is why they have to make systems that do it easier, better and faster

Comment: But there aren’t any that aren’t solved with just more mass?

Comment: they could be, but its impossible to get that mass to space

Comment: Unless you get it in space...

Comment: which would take a reallly long time.

Comment: You are posing this as an either-or question. It is not. The answer to the question raised in the title is $\text{\huge{YES}}$.

Comment: I disagree. It’s a question because there could be some major factors that no amount of additional mass would solve. That is what I am trying to identify. Is the rotating station feasible with higher mass for shielding or is tensile strength of current materials too low? Is a self contained system feasible today with enough mass? Are there other considerations more mass won’t solve? That is the question. If so, then it is a technology problem. If not, then it is a mass problem we’re trying to reduce via technology.

Comment: @oeste There is a concept used by NASA called Technology Readiness Level. Many of the concepts that you think would be solved simply by sending more mass into space are at TRL 3 or below, which means we do not know how to do it.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @oeste Many of the problems could be solved by more mass - by some 3-5 orders of magnitude more mass than we have capability of sending currently. And then comes the exponential nature of problems. Large rotating station with massive shielding requires super-massive structure to keep it from breaking up, and outrageous amounts of propellant for station-keeping. At certain (not at all distant) point extra mass becomes a liability and while it can be solved by *even more mass*, we're gerring into 'artificial planets' territory here really fast.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion based. It's an interesting question but there's no definitive, science based answer.

Comment: @GdD I think the answer posted 3 hours after your comment suggests that reasonably good, definitive, and science based answers are possible. "No one can answer this question" predictions are sometimes premature, and quickly closing them rather than finding out what answers are possible can be more self-fulfilling prophesy than helpful.

Comment: The mass problem would be completely solved by going asteroid mining. I think going to Mars is the wrong direction (immediately back down into a different gravity well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While more mass/more budget would solve some/many problems, there are still space-habitation related issues that can't *sustainably* be solved by throwing mass at them.

First, **volume.** We could easily build pressurized torus with a diameter of over a hundred meters to build an artificial-gravity system and assemble it here on Earth. Provided with a moderately skilled welder, a civil engineer, and lots of steel, it wouldn't be too difficult to build--the difficulty lies in launching it. Even if you were able to swallow the launch mass-costs of such a structure, it simply wouldn't fit inside a rocket. It would need to be either built in modules and then assembled in space or constructed from raw materials on orbit (using welding robots or something). Both these cases face engineering challenges that cannot be overcome with more mass: for the modular approach, the individual modules would need to be built with high-strength docking ports and you'd likely want to make the modules inflatable (Bigelow-style) because even putting largest fairing volumes available today are rather small for human habitation. For the manufactured-in-space approach, you need to develop the technology to build robots or suits that can weld, handle, and cut material on orbit, which is not simple. Both approaches (modular and manufactured) require additional technological innovation and can't be sidestepped by simply adding more mass

Secondly, **life support**. Even with no mass limits, building a life support system like you'd want on a space station is a difficult engineering challenge. Managing the atmosphere, scrubbing CO2, filtering water, and all those other tasks that are required to maintain a habitable environment inside what is essentially a closed ecosystem is challenging. In fact, it might even be more difficult on a larger station as there are more potential failure points and a larger volume of space that needs to be handled by the environmental controls. Yes, it would probably be possible to offset issues by using large amounts of disposable components like chemical CO2 scrubbers and similar devices, but this just increases overall workload of the station's inhabitants and reduces efficiency.

Third, **human-operability**. Some things need to be light in spaceflight because they need to be used by humans. Space suits are a great example: adding more mass wouldn't make the suit more flexible or solve the existing issues that spacesuits have--more technological development is required.

I could go on, but in short, while throwing more mass at the issue can sidestep many problems like radiation, there are numerous technological issues that can't be so easily circumvented.

Comment: Nitpick but I don't think the "bigger might be more difficult" subpoint under life support is very strong. Bigger means *more redundancy* (any one failure is less of the whole) and *more reserves* (a bigger mass of air/water/food/etc. to absorb transient problems). The limiting case of "go big" is to bring a planet with you, which will keep a few billion people alive for at least a century of mismanagement.

Comment: More mass could eliminate spacesuits entirely, by allowing for pods with manipulators, or other hard suits. One of the major complications in a suit design is remaining flexible while under pressure, and even that pressure is so low as to require complex prebreathing sessions. A hardsuit or pod would be much more convenient (perhaps with flexible gloves on the end of hard arms. More mass eliminates the need for flexibility in suits, pure oxygen atmospheres, and risk of getting the bends.

Comment: @Innovine If hardsuit technology or personal-pods were superior to the current suits, wouldn't they be in use already? The fact that they aren't leads me to believe there's a technological limitation holding them back. iirc NASA has seriously considered replacing spacesuits with personal pods multiple times but the idea hasn't gotten anywhere, and not due to the extra mass.

Comment: @Dragongeek I think mass restrictions are a big factor, but feel free to quote some research on it.